# Avoid Google Analytics from categorizing pop-up as entrance

Tags: javascript, popup, google-analytics, tracking

in my google analytics account there is a page tracked usually opened as a javascript window.open() pop-up (same domain as referring page).

unfortunately, g.a. categorizes the pop-up page as entrance, although it is just a step in the whole navigation flow.

how can i avoid this?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use GA events.

On your popup page: (untested)

```
<script>
    window.opener.pageTracker._trackPageview(window.location.href);
</script>
```

and remove the existing tracking code from the popup entirely.

---

*note: I'm not sure if this will be displayed as an "entrance." but it may be worth a shot.*

Comment: thanks david, i'll test this.

i actually noticed that i also have pop-ups on other domains, where its not that easy for me to change the tracking code.

is there a chance by changing the pop-up code instead the cracking-code on the pop-up page?

Comment: hm, i don't know if you can do what you want cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

http://aktagon.com/projects/jquery/google-analytics

This Jquery GA plugin has a lot of options,  a big one being that you can set certain pages to be ignore/categorized in certain ways.

Also, If you setup a funnel or goal with regular expressions, you could set it to only match sites from your homepage and off (and not the popup.)

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding because of my improper description. i _want_ tot track the popup but it should not bei marked es new entrance, because it is just one step out of many in a certain flow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution here, but I do know the problem: window.open does not carry the HTTP referrer through (on some browsers at least), and without a same-site referrer Google Analytics considers a pageview to start a new (direct-access) session.

This [blog post from 2006](http://www.nathanm.com/ie-windowopen-and-no-referrer-referer/) has some possible solutions - I can't vouch for any of them though.